# How can Scriptella generate a log file?

Tags: logging, etl, scriptella

I want Scriptella to generate a log file for each raw file to be ETLed just a log4j does for a java application. How to make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Any logging API can be called directly from the ETL file. Probably the easiest way to achieve that would be to use a script driver with a built-in Rhino support(JavaScript):

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <connection id="log4j" driver="script"/>

    <connection id="jul" driver="script"/>

    <script connection-id="jul">
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("testLogger").info("This is JUL message");
    </script>

    <script connection-id="log4j">
        //For demo purposes!!!
        //Configures log4j to use console for output
        //Normally log4j should be configured by using a config file
        org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();
    </script>

    <script connection-id="log4j">
        org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("testLoggerName").info("This is LOG4J message");
    </script>
</etl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a connection like this

```
<connection id="log" driver="text" url="D:/tmp/out.log"/>
```

and then use it in your query like this

```
<query connection-id="dbConnectionIn">
    select * from table
    <script connection-id="log">
        Result  $column1, $comun2 
    </script>
</query>
```

This will now log it to the file under D:/tmp

Comment: the problem here lies that if i want to etl multiple files using a single etl.xml then your solution will override the previous log outputs in the out.log file.

Comment: u can append a date to the file name in the properties in that case. so each time u run ETL it will create new files

Comment: just to give more clarity I have something like this :    <properties>  logfile=out-${etl.date.today('yyyyMMddHHmmssZ')}.log
</properties> and then I declare connection as  <connection id="log" driver="text" url="$logfile"/>  . This will create multiple log files the number of time you execute the ETL. Hope this Helps.